# Finding unknown repeating patterns in a string consisting numbers

Tags: c#, string, pattern-matching, repeat

I've been struggling with this for a week.

I have a string like this: **1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1.....**

What I need to find: **1 1 0**

example 2: **1 1 2 0 2 2 1 0 1 1 2 0 2 2 1 0 1 1 2 0 2 2 1 0 1 1 2 0 2 2 1 0 ....**

What I need to find: **1 1 2 0 2 2 1 0**

example 3: **1 1 2 3 1 0 1 1 2 3 1 0 1 1 2 3 1 0 1 1 2 3 1 0 1 1 2 3 1 0...**

**112310**

etc. etc.

My code as now:

```
private string tekrarArama(double[] mods)
        {
            string part1 = "";
            string part2 = "";

            string patern = "";


            int number1 = mods.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < mods.Length; i++)
            {
                part1 = "";
                part2 = "";
                for (int j = 0; j < number1; j++)
                {

                    part1 += mods[j] + ",";
                }


                for (int k = 0; k < mods.Length; k++)
                {

                    part2 += mods[k] + ",";
                }


                int actualcount = Regex.Matches(part2, part1).Count;

                int count = part2.Replace(",", "").Length / part1.Replace(",", "").Length;


                if (part2.IndexOf(bolum1) >= 0 && actualcount == count )
                {
                    patern = part2.Substring(part2.IndexOf(part1),part1.Length);
                }

                number1--;


            }

            return patern;

        }
```

It creates two copies of the string and deletes 1 character at a time from one of the strings in each iteration, to find the smallest repeating pattern.

It's a mess and doesn't work very well at all. 
How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a [longest repeated substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem)?

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek I don't think he's looking for the **longest**. In the first example given, 110 is not the longest repeated substring.

Comment: You might have better luck first describing your algorithm as pseudo-code and doing desk runs with pencil and paper.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek more like, shortest string :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for something simple and don't need optimal complexity, here's a concise way to represent the query.

```
string FindPattern(string text)
{
    if (text == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return Enumerable
        .Range(1, text.Length / 2)
        .Where(n => text.Length % n == 0)
        .Select(n => text.Substring(0, n))
        .Where(pattern => Enumerable
            .Range(0, text.Length / pattern.Length)
            .SelectMany(i => pattern)
            .SequenceEqual(text))
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Note that the complexity here is quadratic in the worst case, so it's not a good idea to use it for very long strings.