# Finding non-overlapping repeating sub-strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, repeat, longest-substring

My problem is similar to finding the longest repeating non-overlapping sub-strings but in this manner. Example, my input array is `0,0,0,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,0,0`

The longest repeating and non-overlapping sub-string in this input is `121` with the count as `3`
Now, remove the occurrences of `121` from the input array and replace them with `-1`.

My input now becomes: `0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,2,0,0`
Now again find the same sub-strings.

Note: -1 shall not be included in the answer. So, the next longest non-overlapping and repeating sub-string is `00` with count as `2`.

Remove occurrences of 0,0 from the input which then becomes: `0,-1,-1,-1,2,-1`
The only occurrences now are 0 and 2 which are of length 1. So, here we stop.

I am only able to think of brute force which will be O(n<sup>3</sup>). Tried thinking of suffix trees too but don't know how to include the non-overlapping condition in it.

My very naive implementation:

Because I want my substring to have count as atleast 2, it can have length maximum as N/2 (N is the size of input array)

```
for len = N/2 to 1:
    // find all sub-strings of length as "len" in the input sequence
    for i=0 to N-len+1
        // the sub-string is s[i... (i+len)]
        // find non-overlapping count of this sub-string in the input sequence using KMP
        int count = find_Count();
        // take the substring with maximum count, let it be "r"
    end
    modify the array to place replace non-overlapping occurrences of "r" with -1
end
```

As you can see above, the complexity is O(N<sup>3</sup>).

Any optimal solution, hints or explanation can be of some help.

Thanks

Comment: You did not choose a language but here is an related implementation in C# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995978/

Comment: Is this one better? http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-repeating-and-non-overlapping-substring/. And btw you want speudo code or a language specifique implementation?

Comment: I am doing in Java. And that GFG link is the exact problem with an add on. The substring needs to be repeatedly found, eg. in above explanation, when we found 121, we remove its occurrence from the input array and again apply the same algorithm. Already the complexity is O(n2) with high space complexity. My input can be of length 10^6 also. Thus, the DP approach will not perform good.